# Web browsers unreliable in WSL2 + xfce4 + xrdp

Tags: linux, networking, browser, wsl2

I'm running an xfce4 desktop in WSL2 via xrdp from my local machine (I'm running Windows 10, so I can't use WSLg). This mostly works fine, except that web browsers (I've tried Firefox and Chromium) both seem to have really patchy networking performance. Sometimes remote sites load, but most often they don't and time out.

The strange thing is that if I `curl` the same sites from a terminal inside the same RDP session, I consistently see HTML content loading. So it's something specific the browsers are doing, but I don't know enough about the intricacies of browser networking and the network stack under WSL2 to debug the problem.

Has anyone else had simliar problems, or can point me in the right direction for information / tips on how to fix this situation?

Comment: I don't think it's going to matter, but what distribution are you using in WSL?  If I'm going to attempt to reproduce, I'd like to make sure I get it as close to what you are using as I can.  Any special customizations you've done like Systemd or anything else you've installed?  For instance, installing Chromium in Ubuntu typically means installation via Snap, which would require Systemd.

Comment: Just for reference, I'm currently typing this particular comment while connected via RDP to an Ubuntu 20.04 instance in WSL2 running Xfce4 with Firefox.  This is from the localhost.  While the keyboard is a bit laggy, I haven't seen any problems with sites not loading so far.  I'll browse a bit more.  Might even load Selenium to automate some browsing to see if I can break it over time.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thanks for looking into it! I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, no special customisations, I installed Chromium via apt according to instructions I found on someone's blog. I'm starting to suspect it's something to do with Windows-side corporate networking config of this specific laptop.

Comment: Coincidentally, I was just headed back over here to update -- The RDP window has been open all day on my end (after killing the screen lock process), and I just did more browsing without issue.  The corporate network configuration is a likely suspect, yes. 
 Still odd on your end that `curl` is working for you, but the browsers are timing out.  No VPN in play, just the corporate network, right?